# How to set uniqueKey field in JSON based Solr Schema

Tags: solr

I am using JSON based Solr schema to create custom indexes in Sitecore V10.2 docker. After rebuilding my custom index, I am getting following error :

[image: Missing uniqueKey id field]

Although, when I checked the fields in the custom index collection, id field is already present. If I try to override/create it again, I am getting duplicate field error message.

Can anyone help me out please !!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the schema from Solr URL. Select the Solr collection and you'll get a option called schema. From there you can update the fields.

[image]

You can get more detail from below URL-

https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_0/schema-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **managed-schema** file within your custom SOLR core.

This can be located for example here on SOLR VM:

> E:\solr-8.4.0\server\solr\CUSTOM_CORE_NAME\conf

This file should begin like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>_uniqueid</uniqueKey>
```

If it does not start as above, then i suspect that you have not **populated mananaged schema**. This can be done by navigating to the control panel and clicking the link Populate Managed Schema.

NEXT SUGGESTION:
Check your custom core config file. Is index all fields set to true?

< indexAllFields >true</ indexAllFields >

If not then you need to manually add the field.

Comment: My managed-schema file looks like this :
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

I am using Solr in cloud mode & running inside solr-container in docker. So I don't have access to managed-schema file. I don't even have conf folder under my custom core folder. All I have is data folder under which there are 3 folders (index, snapshot_metadata & tlog) & core.properties file which has metadata about the core.

Comment: Ok. Please see can you share your custom core sitecore config file? See new suggestion in answer below.